# Variable importance logistic and random forest

Tags: logistic, feature-selection, random-forest, importance

I have created variable importance plots using varImp in R for both a logistic and random forest model. I want to compare how the logistic and random forest differ in the variables they find important. Of course, they do this in a different way: logistic takes the absolute value of the t-statistic and the random forest the mean decrease in Gini.

Now, when I plot the variable importance plots for the logistic and the random forest, I find that the logistic and the random forest model handle factorial variables in a different way, whilst the random forest model takes the total group, the logistic regression takes one of the possible factor outcomes.

For example, I have a group US states with 50 factors, the logistic regression would take New York as an important factor, whilst the random forest model takes **the group** US states as the important factor.

How can I solve this for the logistic regression? Could I just add all the values for the variable importance to get the total group importance?

Comment: i don't know if you can sum up t-stats like that... might be better to use change in deviance. which varImp() function are you using?

Comment: Just using varImp(mylogit, scale = TRUE) from the caret package.

Comment: when I tried caret::varImp on the random forest, it doesn't give me a collective importance... ok so you fitted using randomForest but not caret

Comment: Yes, sorry. I didn't know caret and randomForest produced different results.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is most likely not a good idea.

1. If you have many coefficients that are not very useful, i.e low T statistics, but adding up 50 of them might give you something huge... which just doesn't make sense.
2. T-statistic doesn't take into account the explained variance. Worst scenario, one of one of your categories end up in a sweet spot, it has low number of observations and by chance a small standard error, a huge t-statistic. Adding this up to your term inflates the importance.

We can use an example below:

```
library(survival)
library(randomForest)
library(caret)

da = survival::diabetic[,-1]
# make age categories
da$age = cut(diabetic$age,10)
da$status = factor(da$status) 

glm_mdl = glm(status ~ .,data=da,family=binomial)

rf_mdl = randomForest(status ~ .,data=da)
```

If we look at the summary of glm, seems like age has an effect, but if you sum up the tstat for all age, you end up with something huge:

```
    Coefficients:
                Estimate Std. Error z value Pr(>|z|)    
(Intercept)     1.063128   1.101749   0.965   0.3346    
laserargon     -0.048476   1.151578  -0.042   0.9664    
age(6.7,12.4]   0.964098   0.501488   1.922   0.0545 .  
age(12.4,18.1]  0.500876   0.525536   0.953   0.3406    
age(18.1,23.8]  2.191287   1.144998   1.914   0.0556 .  
age(23.8,29.5]  0.945382   1.333947   0.709   0.4785    
age(29.5,35.2]  0.849438   1.361294   0.624   0.5326    
age(35.2,40.9]  1.497774   1.425724   1.051   0.2935    
age(40.9,46.6]  0.545537   1.312921   0.416   0.6778    
age(46.6,52.3]  1.565862   1.385946   1.130   0.2586    
age(52.3,58.1]  0.945929   1.500791   0.630   0.5285    
eyeright        0.484579   0.293928   1.649   0.0992 .  
trt            -1.098955   0.295500  -3.719   0.0002 ***
risk            0.097595   0.103325   0.945   0.3449    
time           -0.094334   0.009613  -9.814   <2e-16 ***
```

We check the change in deviance (how good it is at reducing prediction error), it's actually quite little:

```
anova(glm_mdl)

          Df Deviance Resid. Df Resid. Dev
NULL                    393     528.15
laser  1    0.317       392     527.84
age    9    3.716       383     524.12
eye    1    3.110       382     521.01
trt    1   26.404       381     494.61
risk   1    5.107       380     489.50
time   1  179.399       379     310.10
```

If you like the variable importance to reflect how useful the variable is at predicting correctly, I think a fairer comparison might be change in deviance, so we can try something like:

```
v_glm = anova(glm_mdl)[-1,2,drop=FALSE]
v_glm = v_glm[order(v_glm[,1]),drop=FALSE,]
v_glm[,1] = 100*v_glm[,1]/max(v_glm[,1])

v_rf = as.matrix(varImp(rf_mdl))
v_rf =  v_rf[order(v_rf),]
```

And we get the estimate if we sum up the importance as you raised:

```
v_glm_sum = as.matrix(varImp(glm_mdl))
age_row = grepl("age",rownames(v_glm_sum))
v_glm_sum = rbind(age=sum(v_glm_sum[age_row,]),v_glm_sum[!age_row,drop=FALSE,])
v_glm_sum =  v_glm_sum[order(v_glm_sum),]
```

Now plot and we can see the sum of the importance of categories will be inflated, so most likely the deviance is something closer, for comparison:

```
par(mfrow=c(1,3))
barplot(t(v_rf),horiz=TRUE,main="rf",las=2)
barplot(t(v_glm),horiz=TRUE,main="glm_deviance",las=2)
barplot(t(v_glm_sum),horiz=TRUE,main="glm_sum_scores",las=2)
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks, you made it much clearer!

Comment: This is an old answer, but I should provide a clarification: `anova` in R performs *sequential* sum of squares, which wouldn't be what you want here.  I like the approach but I would use `car::Anova` to assess each variable appropriately.